# Playing .ogg video files on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, video, software-rec, ogg

By default, Windows XP has no support for .ogg video files. What can be used to read and play these files?

Answer (score 6):

You can use VLC media player, that will play almost anything. See http://www.videolan.org/vlc/.

Comment: The media file is rare that can't be played in VLC.

Answer (score 2):

[Ogg media plugin for Windows Media Player](https://www.xiph.org/dshow/downloads/)

Answer (score 0):

[foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) can play .ogg files.

EDIT: But probably not video .ogg files - sorry!

Comment: Maybe audio - this is about video files in .ogg

Comment: I probably didn't notice "video" because I didn't realise there was such a thing as a video .ogg file. Thanks for the heads up - do you think I should delete my answer?